# Creating a borderless textfield (Titanium studio Android)

Tags: android, ios, textfield, titanium-mobile, borderless

I'm new to Titanium Studio. I would like to create a Textfield without border for Android. I saw there is a method for Ios, but didn't find any for android. Can any one please suggest me how can I create a textfield with no border for android. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it that you just want to use a label?  How would a user know they can edit this if it doesn't have a border around it to indicate it is an editable field?

Comment: When user taps the label near to it I will focus the textfield. So that's not a problem. Please tell me if I can make a textfield with no border. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the current trick is to apply a transparent image on the Android platform.  This also appears to work on IOs as well, though I imagine the the preferred option for IOS is to set borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSYLE_NONE

```
var myText = Ti.UI.createTextField({
  backgroundImage: 'images/transparent.jpeg'
});
```

Comment: It just works for Ios but not for Android. And it's clearly specified in documentation.

Comment: Sorry for being late. I was busy with other tasks. Thank you. It works.